# AVAudioPlayer Play fails after returning to the app from Locked state or just app sleeping for some time

Tags: ios, maui, avaudioplayer

I need to play a lot of short sounds quickly and using a separate `AVAudioPlayer` for each sound. I am using here `C#` because I use `.Net MAUI` but it doesn't matter. Everything works like on native iOS.
Preloading sounds. `AVAudioPlayer` object is stored for later use (it is not garbage collected because it is stored on the singleton that is alive as long as the app is running).

```
var player = new AVAudioPlayer(url, null, out _);
player.PrepareToPlay();
```

I don't need to play them in background so initialization of the session looks like this

```
AVAudioSession.SharedInstance().SetCategory(AVAudioSessionCategory.Playback);
AVAudioSession.SharedInstance().SetActive(true);
```

Playing a sound

```
audioPlayer.Play();
```

It works fine but when I lock the screen and unlock it and then call `Play()` it returns false from `Play()` and not playing any sounds. Is there a way to get an error message about the problem that prevents it playing?

```
audioPlayer.Play(); // Returns false
```

I tried to initialize session again by setting category but that doesn't fix the problem.

Recreating `AVAudioPlayer` fixes the problem but that isn't a good fix because I would like fixing the problem before user taps on a button to play a sound.

I haven't found any way to know beforehand that after returning into the app playing sounds is broken. Because a lot of times it works fine even after lock/unlock. Reloading all the sounds (which are 88 in my case) upon every user is returning to the foreground isn't a good idea because playing sounds isn't the core functionality of the app.

Any ideas how to fix it properly?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [iOS lifecycle events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/app-lifecycle?view=net-maui-8.0#ios), the app comes to Background modes thus `DidEnterBackground` is invoked when the screen is locked.

When it is unlocked, the app will enter foreground and `WillEnterForeground` method is invoked.

> Recreating AVAudioPlayer fixes the problem but that isn't a good fix because I would like fixing the problem before user taps on a button to play a sound.

So you may override the `WillEnterForeground` method and recreate AVAudioPlayer in it,

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : MauiUIApplicationDelegate
{
    protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp() => MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();

    public override void WillEnterForeground(UIApplication application)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("App entering background state.");
        //You may active or initialize the session here
        //AVAudioSession.SharedInstance().SetActive(true);

    }
    public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication application)
    {
        // When the screen is locked, this method is invoked
        Console.WriteLine("App entering background state.");
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That's not ok because not every time sounds stop playing. A lot of times it works and if it works I wouldn't wanna reload all sounds (just in case) every time user leaves and app and returns because it takes a few sec. It would be ideal to be able to know whether everything is broken before calling Play()

Comment: Why not add some if statements in the method? If ```audioPlayer.Play();``` return true, then don't have to reload it.

Comment: that's what I did for now. But it isn't good because user has to tap to play the sound and then it won't play until everything loads and it is 88 sounds. I need to do it preemptively but I don't know how to know when Play will fail before calling it (locking the screen or putting the app to sleep doesn't always kill the sound, so upon returning to the app you can't be sure whether it broke or not). I could load 1 by 1 instead of 88 on Play fail but that is also bad because it will have a loading hiccup before each sound. I better wait for 1.5 sec once to load everything and then it will play.

Comment: Just a thought. If adding the audio in Background mode, will it still break?